# START COUNTING IF VALUE EXISTS GOOGLE SHEETS

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I have a column with ID'S this column is dynamic so it will grow up, next to it I have a count formula for the number of text appearing this one:

```
=COUNTIF(F3:F12,"?*")+COUNT(F3:F12)
```

I would like to have a formula to count just when exist an ID if not will be "".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula-

```
 =COUNTA(IFERROR(INDEX($E$3:$K$18,,MATCH(A2,$E$1:$K$1,0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Actually cool but I don't need the match just that the colum A has values if not formula don't show me nothing, Thanks

Comment: You need `MATCH()` otherwise, how you will know that ID is exist. If you want to show blank when id is not exist then could try-`=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A2,$E$1:$K$1,0))="","",COUNTA(INDEX($E$3:$K$18,,MATCH(A2,$E$1:$K$1,0))))`

Comment: Another formula is `=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER($E$2:$K,$E$1:$K$1=A2)))`

Comment: I get it but actually I just need some not blank formula really simple

Comment: I made it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the formulas I was looking for:

```
=IF(A4<>"", (D4/$B$2), "")
```